# Modifing .class file in .jar

Tags: java, class, decompiling, recompile

As follow of this thread: [Resource to url java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034099/resource-to-url-java) I need to edit the .class inside of the .jar . I manage to read the class file with jd-gui I can't change the text of the class file. Is there a simple way to change the line mentioned in the thread ?

Comment: A simple way? I mean, you can always decompile, edit, recompile, and re-package. If you're asking about modifying classes on load it's harder.

Comment: yes totaly that